# Instantiate View Controller Swift 3 Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

How can I segue to a tab bar controller? Theres 2 view controllers on tabs with navigation controllers and a navigation controller on the tab bar controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PendingOverview", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PendingOverviewVC") as! PendingOverViewController
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
self.present(nc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Thank you

Comment: You have asked about segue in your question and in code you are using present?

Comment: Yeah sorry I was using the literal term "segue". Thanks though

Comment: Have you try my solution is it works for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Storyboard` set identifier to `UITabbarController` and then using `instantiateViewController` present that `UITabbarController`.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PendingOverview", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarIdentifier") as! UITabbarController
if let vcs = tabbarVC.viewControllers, 
   let nc = vcs.first as? UINavigationController,
   let pendingOverVC = nc.topViewController as? PendingOverViewController {

      pendingOverVC.pendingResult = pendingResult
}
self.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How do I then pass a value because I'm getting nil on the end view controller

Comment: On which viewController you want to pass value first or second and both this viewController are embeded in NavigationController?

Comment: let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyTabController") as? MyViewController vc.datatopass = datatopass

Comment: Yes it goes tabbed vc, nav vc, end vc.

Comment: @Denis Don't add code here ,edit your question with new code so that it will easy to read what you are trying.