# Error Application tried to present modally an active controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In have a UITabBarController with several UIViewControllers. Inside one of the controllers, when a certain condition is met, I want to instantiate another UIViewController which is a child of the same UITabBarController. 
I keep getting this error "*Application tried to present modally an active controller*", but I don't understand how is scheduleNavController already active. I looked up several answers on SO, but I still don't understand what is my mistake and how can I solve it?
The flow of the app is like this: WelcomeViewController,LoginViewController,UITabBarController and the children of the UITabBarController.

```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let tabController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CentralTabBarControllerID") as! UITabBarController

 if let viewControllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
     let scheduleNavController = viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
     let scheduleVC = scheduleNavController.childViewControllers[0] as! Schedule

       tabController.present(scheduleNavController, animated: true, completion: {
          scheduleVC.segmentedControlIndexReceivedFromClaimDetail = self.segmentedControlIndex
             })

        }
```

[image]

Comment: You retrieve `scheduleNavController` from the array of active view controllers and then try and present it morally.

Comment: @Paulw11 What should I do then ?

Comment: Why not simply change the `selectedIndex` of your tab bar controller?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I have used your suggested method. However, could you please post an answer fixing the code from my original question without using `selectedIndex`? I have seen lots of questions asked using the method I tried in my original question. I think such answer would be helpful for other SO members. Thanks

Comment: Changing the selected index is the correct approach though;

Comment: @Paulw11  I had seen this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593088 and thought he was right too.

Comment: That is segueing to a new tab bar controller. As I understand it, you already have a tab bar controlller and just want to activate the appropriate tab

Comment: I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas Oetjen suggestion to use the `selectedIndex` of the UITabBarController I have come up with another solution. However, I still don't know exactly how I should fix my code from the original question to make it work.

```
 //select index of the UIViewController we want to switch to 
// get the UINavigationController for the tab we want to switch to
// get UIViewController to which we want to pass data 
 self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
 let scheduleNavController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
 let scheduleVC = scheduleNavController.childViewControllers[0] as! Schedule
 scheduleVC.segmentedControlIndexReceivedFromClaimDetail = self.segmentedControlIndex

//remove the the current UIViewController from which we switch to another controller above.
 let claimDetailNav = tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! UINavigationController
  let claimDetailVC = claimDetailNav.childViewControllers[1] as! ClaimDetail
  claimDetailVC.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: You don't need to present it, it will be displayed once you change the index of the tab bar controller. What you might want to do is update the data that is displayed.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Is this the correct practice to remove the current UIViewController after switching to another tab ?

Comment: Yes; technically, you do not _remove_ it, but change the tab index to _display_ a different one. The little backdraw is that all the view controller stays in memory, so in rare cases you might want to clean up some memory.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I added new line of code: `claimDetailVC.removeFromParentViewController()`, is this not releasing the current viewcontroller from memory?

Comment: No, you should not remove it when it is in a tab view controller. Just change the selected index.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Should I use `.dismiss(animated:_,completion:_)` instead? The flow of the app is like this: user taps on Claim, segue to ClaimDetail, tap on a button which  selects tab bar index to 1 which is == to Sechdule, so in this case I need to either remove or dismiss ClaimDetail because if the user taps back on the tab Claim, then ClaimDetail will be at the top of the stack.

Comment: Now I understand. Yes, call dismiss and then change the selected index.